# Is it faster to cast within filter() or cast new withColumn(), then filter in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, filter, casting

Pretty straight forward. Is it faster to run

```
df.filter(col("date_col").cast("timestamp") >= lit(my_timestamp) )
```

or

```
df.withColumn("date_col_cast_timestamp", col("date_col").cast("timestamp") ) \
  .filter("date_col_cast_timestamp" >= lit(my_timestamp) )
```

or one more...

```
df.withColumn("date_col_cast_timestamp", col("date_col").cast("timestamp") ) \
  .withColumn("my_timestamp", lit(my_timestamp)) \
  .filter("date_col_cast_timestamp" >= col("my_timestamp"))
```

If you could explain why that would be greatly appreciated. I'm not the best with understanding spark and when I tried doing a filter(cast >= lit) I noticed thousands of tasks were created compared to a couple hundred. Not sure if that's better or worse. I couldn't tell if it was slower or faster though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to compare different differents solution is to use `explain` fonction and compare the plan.

In your case, I think that the first solution is better

```
df.filter(col("date_col").cast("timestamp") >= lit(my_timestamp) )
```

In other solution you are using `withColumn` that create a whole new column, that is not the case in your first solution.

This solution can be acceptable if you want, in the future, to use both, date and timestamps column multiple time.